# How to dynamically allocate memory for nested pointer struct?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, class, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to dynamically allocate memory for a nested struct that happens to be a pointer. I have written some made-up code below to try and illustrate my problem.

These two structs are found in two separate header files, also the code is under one namespace.

***Tiles.h***

```
struct Tiles
{
    int* m_noOfSections;
    int* m_noOfTilesInSecs;
    char* m_TileName;
};
// functions omitted
```

***Flooring.h***

```
struct Flooring
{
    Tiles* m_Tiles;
    int m_noOfTiles;
    char* m_FlooringName;
};
void read(Tiles&);
```

I am working on a function definition for **Flooring.h** where I have to dynamically allocate an array of `Tiles`, the size of the array is determined earlier on in this function from user input.

I've tried using the following code but ran into issues:

***Flooring.cpp***

```
void read(Flooring&Flr) 
{
      Tiles* tiles;
      tiles = new Tiles[Flr.m_noOfTiles];

      for (int i = 0; i < Flr.m_noOfTiles; i++) {
          cout << i + 1 << ": ";
          read(tiles[i]);
      }
}
```

Note: The `read(tiles[i]);` [declaration: `void read(Tiles&)`] function assigns values to the data members of `Tiles`. I have tested the functions in the `Tiles` files and they are working as intended. So I have not included the code for those. I believe the issue lies in my **Flooring.cpp** implementation file.

My expectation is that that the above read function would assign values to:
`tiles[i].m_noOfSections`, `tiles[i].m_noOfTilesinSecs`, `tiles[i].m_tileName`

One of the issues is that I do not have a chance to input `tileName`, when running the code it skips the part where I would normally input a `tileName`.

The output would be as follows:

```
Enter the number of sets of tiles: Enter number of sections: [user is able 
    to input value here, but not before when asked to enter the number of the set of tiles]
```

***Tiles.cpp***

```
void read(char* tileName)
{
    cout << "Enter tile name: ";
    read(tileName, 15, "error message") ;
}
```

The function definition for the `read` function with three parameters can be found below. This function was pre-defined in this assignment. I have also reviewed the function and I don't see any problems with it, but I will post it regardless if it helps.

```
void read(char* str, int len, const char* errorMessage)
{
      bool ok;
      do 
      {
         ok = true;
         cin.getline(str, len+1, '\n');
         if (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
            ok = false;
         }
      }while(!ok && cout << errorMessage);
   }
```

I hope that is enough information, apologies if my formatting isn't adequate, or if my terminology isn't appropriate, I am still quite new to all sorts of programming. Please do let me know if I have forgotten to include some information.

Comment: You might want to emphasize what your question is. It seems that people here are distracted by bad code quality, and provide general advice, instead of solving a particular problem. You might want to delete irrelevant parts of your code to show the problem more clearly. Also provide a `main` function and input which the user enters. See also [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), by which the storage of the elements will be managed automatically and thereby manual memory allocations can be avoided and you can concentrate on the implementations.

That means, have a good start with the followings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>  // std::vector
#include <string>  // std::string

struct Tiles
{
    std::vector<int> m_noOfSections;
    std::vector<int> m_noOfTilesInSecs;
    std::string m_TileName;
};

struct Flooring 
{
    std::vector<Tiles> m_Tiles;
    // int m_noOfTiles; // --> obsolete, as you can get the size by calling `m_Tiles.size()`
    std::string m_FlooringName;
};
```

---

As a side note, in `Flooring`(maybe also in `Tiles`) it does look like, you want to map the `Tiles`'s name to a group of `Tiles`. As per requirements have a look at other data structure like [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair), [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap), [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), [`std::unordered_multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap)
what standard library provides for this scenario.

Comment: No need for m_noOfTiles. m_Tiles.size() returnsthis

Answer (score 2):

new expression doesn't assign anything, it only value-initializes, if you offer those values, or calls constructor and passes arguments to it.

```
tiles = new Tiles[Flr.m_noOfTiles];
```

creates an array of `Flr.m_noOfTiles` class `Tiles` with garbage non-nullptr pointers and values. Memory for underlings are not initialized. It could be done, by offering initializer list.

```
tiles = new Tiles[Flr.m_noOfTiles] { value1, value2, value3 };
```

You have to allocate memory for every pointer. And when it's not needed, deallocate it, in proper order, from most nested to less nested structure.

This might be not a trivial task depending on operations you need and cause quite a hassle in code. It's the reason why C++  have constructors and destructors. So:

1. is there reason why you don't use RAII? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii
2. Is there reason you don't use standard collections, they already implement RAII.
3. Is there reason why you don't use smart pointers?